# Function from init.gradle in build script

Tags: gradle

in my init.gradle I have

```
...
// the last thing in init.gradle
def buildTime() {
   def df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'") //you can change it
   df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
   return df.format(new Date())
}
```

In my build.gradle I want to do something like this:

```
task showTime() << {
    println buildTime()
}
```

But I get "Could not find method buildTime() for arguments [] on root project..."

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 10):

Got the answer from Gradle-Support.
https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-access-a-function-defined-in-init-gradle-in-build-script/6200

Maybe it helps someone else...

The init file is a different context than the build.gradle file. But you can extend a project object (build.gradle delegates to) with a custom property or method (using a closure):

**init.gradle**

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
gradle.allprojects{
  ext.buildTime = {
   def df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'")
   df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
   return df.format(new Date())
   }    
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
task showBuildTime() << {
   println buildTime()
}
```

Comment: this is just the sort of thing that drives folks crazy. doing something as simple as an "include is hopelessly obtuse. p.s., i also believe this could have been solved by defining `showBuildTime()` in the global context ("=" v. "<<").

Comment: I'm using the same solution. But do you know how to call another method defined in project.ext from buildTime() body?

Comment: What about functions with arguments?

Comment: Error:(20, 0) Build script error, unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'buiildTime()'!

Possible causes could be:  
  - you are using Gradle version where the method is absent (<a href="open_gradle_settings">Fix Gradle settings</a>)
  - you didn't apply Gradle plugin which provides the method (<a href="apply_gradle_plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a>)
  - or there is a mistake in a build script (<a href="goto_source">Goto source</a>)

Comment: This looks like you would potentially get a slightly different buildTime per child project, I think you would want to create a single date and reuse.